# How could I make a menu through the whole app

Tags: java, android, layout, menu

I made menus for the Android app I'm working on (using `DrawerLayouts`) one to navigate between different lists and one for settings. I need these menus through the whole app, on all the main pages and the "details" pages (when clicking on items of the list).

**Main page**

[image]

**Navigation Menu**

[image]

**Settings Menu**

[image]

Right now, I'm using `NavigationView` and `fragments` for the main pages. The problem is that I can't find a way to show the "detail" pages on the same fragment view and even if I could or if I showed those on a different fragment view it would be difficult to keep track of navigation (when pressing the back button or using the navigation buttons to go to another main page). I would also like to implement animations between `fragments` (main page to "detail" page and between "detail" pages) so it would really be complicated with separate fragments. So I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to achieve this, or if I should use activities and copy and paste the menus.

Comment: Can you share some screenshots of your application presenting the current look, and how you want it to appear?

Comment: as I understand you want to have single app activity, you can try this https://github.com/Trendyol/medusa  simple navigation between the fragments or a native solution https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started so you will have a menu available throughout the app

Comment: @mohkamfer I added some screenshots of the current look

Comment: @Yura I also want to add animations between the fragments if possible (forgot to mention this) so i'll check what I can do with that, thank you !

Comment: animation is available on both, like slide, fade and etc. about custom ones, I can't say because I didn't have to use